# Can Spring help to prevent caching of html pages on the browser?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, cache-control, sencha-architect

I have a Java/Spring 3.x webapp that uses ExtJS and I use the Sencha Architect to create the front end which results in an automatically generated **app.html** file that loads in the JS and CSS resources that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Auto Generated with Sencha Architect -->
<!-- Modifications to this file will be overwritten. -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>ui</title>
    <script src="ext/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script src="ext/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ext/resources/ext-theme-neptune/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I want to protect this html file with Spring security and this seems to work except that it is often cached in the browser so that it appears to reload even when the user is not logged in. Here is my Spring XML that configures security for my webapp:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/ui/app.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/ui/**" access="permitAll" />

    <form-login
        login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/ui/app.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <csrf/>  <!-- enable csrf protection -->
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider >
        <user-service>
            <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

As you can see I have configured it to protect the **ui/app.html** resource as well as redirect to that page after log in. This works fine until the browser caches the page and causes confusion when the user is logged out and tries to access the same URL.

I was wondering if Spring MVC could be used to load the page via a controller, perhaps modifying the HTTP headers to force the page to expire, but as this is a page that is normally delivered directly by the servlet container and not MVC I'm not sure how I would configure that.

I'd also like to be able to leave my **app.html** file in-situ as it uses resources that are relative to it, and it's also easier to leave it there when working with Sencha Architect.

Comment: I belive the problem is with this <intercept-url pattern="/ui/**" access="permitAll" />, can you change the pattern and see.

Comment: @Vishnu when I do that the page is still cached. I have checked with Fiddler and the browser doesn't try to load it.

Comment: it appears to reload even when the user is not logged in? what does that mean?

Comment: It's possible to set cache headers with Spring MVC, but it's currently something of a pain. 4.2 is supposed to bring a number of improvements about this specific feature.

Comment: @GlennLawrence if you watch your url patern ="/ui/**"  which allows permitAll and then there is a specific pattern /ui/app.html which is protected under a specific role is conflicting, for testing this can you make /ui/** as same as /ui/app.html and then see if you still receive a cached response.

Comment: @Vishnu the Spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html) say "more specific patterns are defined higher in the list" which is the way I have it. I have also tried removing "/ui/**" and it makes no difference to this problem.

Comment: @user3247727 to the user it appears to reload, though in fact it is already in the browser cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will prevent browser caching:

```xml
<http>
    <!-- ... -->
    <headers>
        <cache-control />
    </headers>
</http>
```

It adds `Cache-Control`, `Pragma` and `Expires` headers for every response. More information can be found in reference documentation, section [Security HTTP Response Headers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#headers).

**Update:** This answer was written for *version 3.2* of Spring Security. As of version 4, these headers are included by default.

Comment: I have a spring boot 4.x app and AngularJS. Everything seems to be cached, at least, JS  doesn't get redownloaded. Are you sure those headers are there by default?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose one of the below which depends on how your application is going to serve the resource requests.

1. Using Spring Security
   http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-cache-control
2. Using Extjs
   http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?257086-Is-there-a-simple-way-to-disable-caching-for-an-entire-ExtJS-4-application
3. Using HTML
   http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881

Comment: Thanks, but the ExtJS cache busting method doesn't help when loading the html landing page. Your first link was useful but @homlis83 answered it more succinctly.